# How Can I wait to an element to appears using protractor and my file conf?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to using  protractor to wait to my input 'Username' to appears and then insert value on it. How Can I do it?

```
browser.get('http://localhost:5555/#');
var login = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Username'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) to wait for certain conditions, i.e. for an element to be present or visible.  Use [sendKeys](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys) to fill an input.

```
var login = element(by.id('Username'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(login)).then(function() {
    login.sendKeys('myuser');
});
```

This belongs in your spec, not your config.

Comment: there's no need to resolve the promise returned by `browser.wait`: `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(login)); login.sendKeys('myuser');`

Comment: @FlorentB. You're right, I just find it more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Readability is sometimes a "personal" thing :) Though, the more "flat" the code is - the better, generally speaking.

Comment: `presenceOf` wont check element visibility, use `visibilityOf` or `elementToBeClickable` to be sure that element visible. Since element might exist in DOM but not visible. In this case wait will be successful, but sendKeys might fail

Answer (score 0):

If your's is an Angular App and if you are doing everything right , Then You need not wait for the Element or Page to Load.

Protractor does it for you. Refer API doc for [WaitForAngular](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular)

Also check this you are interested. Wrote more info on my blog [Protractor Over Selenium](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/16/advantages-of-protractor-over-selenium-for-testing-angularjs-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume couple of things

- using shortcut version of element(by.id())
- setting variables to let, instead var
- provide timeout for wait, or it will be endless, and will fail only on test timeout (wasting time for wait)
- provide wait failed error message (3rd parameter in wait function) - better readability on failures
- No need to put `sendKeys()` to callback, protractor controlFlow will execute commands in correct order even without this.

Here is code example:

```
let loginField = $('#Username');
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loginField), 3000, 'Login field should be visible before entering text');
loginField.sendKeys('myuser');
```